# Install xfree86 on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, xorg, ubuntu-12.10

From what I understand they switched from xfree86 to xorg back in 2008 and the xfree86 debian package has been removed as it is outdated.  I however need the xfree86 package for a homework assignment from my university as the make files generated by iMake provided to us needs it.

My knowledge in this area is slim to none as I am brand new to Linux.  Is there a way I can install this package from some other source?

Comment: This is probably [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions); your ultimate aim may related to programming, but the actual problem you're asking for help solving does not. You might want to ask about this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 0):

***WORKING THIS IS A DANGEROUS METHOD KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING BEFORE YOU DO IT, I AM NOT RESPONSABLE FOR YOU MESSING UP YOUR COMPUTER (THE DPKG IS NOT USER FRIENDLY)***

> you may want to google web archive then you can find it in 2008 (If you are lucky) + here is a ubtunu website to try 
>   `http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/(code name for ubtunu release)/main/updates/(package name)`

Find the .deb file (if you are going to make sure that you get the right archtrue) [ex. arm64]
and there might be different names for the .deb it could be xfree86-dev you know for your flavor of linux i found it in debian but not ubuntu

cd to downloads or wherever you put it

Then use the command

```
dpkg -i package-file-name
```

replace package filename with the .deb file

> some things can't be found and you may be stuck.